# How to pass given custom value to <DateField>

Tags: react-admin

Am using `react-admin @2.5.3`.

I would like to show the DOB of people who turn to 18 today using `<DateField/>`, but passing the value in this way does not work.

This function is just for admin, so admin can check if a user is using his real age by checking his ID photo and the DOB of people who turns to 18 years old "today" to see if his birthday is after this dob_18.
Because that `dob_18` is based on the current date, so I would like to calculate from client-side, the `source` field of  should be name of the property in `record` based on its doc https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html, but not sure why doesn't work in this case.

```js
// custom function to manipulate date field
const calculateTime = () => { ... }
<Show title={<IDPhotosTitle />} {...props}>
  <TabbedShowLayout>
    <Tab label="ID">
...
      <DateField 
        record={{"dob_18": calculateTime()}} 
        source="dob_18" 
        label="DOB Check" 
        showTime
        />
...
    </Tab>
  </TabbedShowLayout>
</Show>
```

Can I ask, how can I give `<DateField/>` a custom value calculated in client-side?

Comment: Would kindly mention where you are rendering this `DateField` from? Is it within a `List`?

Comment: @MwamiTovi Thanks for your advice, I have updated my question, please kindly check it.

Comment: Ok, this is within the `<Show>`, cool. So you ONLY want to only display the `dob_18` when a user is turning 18 today, right? What is the expected behavior if that same user came back tomorrow or earlier?

Comment: So this <Show> would include user's ID photo and this <DateField>(the DOB of people who turns to 18 today). So I can check if the DOB on the photo is after that time I calculated which would be different every day.

Comment: I think am missing something. How are you picking the DOB from the ID photo? And is returned by the `calculateTime()` function?

Comment: No, it doesn't pick up the DOB from the photo, it just shows the photo. This function is just for admin, so admin can check if a user is using his real age by checking his ID photo and the DOB of people who turns to 18 years old "today" to see if his birthday is after this dob_18.
Because that `dob_18` is based on the current date, so I would like to calculate from client-side, the `source` field of <DateField> should be name of the property in `record` based on its doc https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html, but not sure why doesn't work in this case.

Comment: Hi, if this isn't sensitive code, can you share the full code via https://gist.github.com/ or https://codesandbox.io/ so that I try re-creating the issue?